# Show that $P_n(F)$ is generated by $\{1, x, \dots, x^n \}$. Differentiating between $\text{span}(S) \subseteq W$ and $\text{span}(S) = W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that $P_n(F)$ is generated by $\{1, x, \dots, x^n \}$.

---

**My Work**

$$S = \{1, x, \dots, x^n\}$$

$$W = \{ a_n w^n + a_{n - 1} w^{n - 1} + \dots + a_0 : a \in F \}$$

Let $x \in \text{span}(S)$.

Therefore, $x = c_1 x^0 + c_2 x^1 + \dots + c_n x^n$ for some scalars $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$ in $F$.

We have $S \subseteq W$ where $W$ is a subspace of $P_n(F)$.

Therefore, there are $w \in W$ such that $w = c_1 x^0 + c_2 x^1 + \dots + c_n x^n$.

Therefore, $\text{span}(S) \subseteq W$

---

I have two questions:

1. Is my solution correct? If not, what is the error and what is the correct solution?
2. Instead of $\text{span}(S) \subseteq W$, I have also seen my textbook describe this as $\text{span}(S) = W$. I am having trouble understanding how these two are interchangeable; indeed, it would seem like they should not be, since $S$ is only a subset of $W$, which means that $W$ could contain other elements and, therefore, linear combinations that are NOT spanned by $S$. So, again, how does this make sense?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to answer these two questions.

Comment: Do not to denote at the same time the variable of your polynomials *and* a general element of the span of $S$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the response. Are you referring to the $x$ in $S$ and the $x$ in $W$? I should use different variables?

Comment: If they are referring to different things, then using the same letter to denote both is a bad idea, you surely agree?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, you are absolutely correct. I should have known better. I will edit it now for clarity. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is that better?

Comment: You should say "$x = c_1x^0 + c_2x^1 + ... + c_nx^n$ for some scalars $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ in $F$". Omit statement about vectors in that line. This is because $0 \in F$ so we can decide which $x^i$'s to have and which ones not to have.

Comment: @VikrantDesai You mean we can decide by selecting certain scalars $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ to be equal to $0$, which then makes the relevant vector also 0?

Comment: @ThePointer Absolutely Yes.

Comment: @VikrantDesai Interesting. Thank you for clarifying this. I will edit my post.

Comment: @ThePointer You can't say "Let $S \subset W$". Instead, say "We have $S \subset W$.

Comment: @VikrantDesai you're right. I will update the OP. Thank you again for the assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53605/discussion-between-vikrant-desai-and-the-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Vikrant Desai clarified my misunderstanding:

We have established that $\text{span}(S) \subseteq W$.

We also know that $W = \{ a_n w^n + a_{n - 1} w^{n - 1} + \dots + a_0 : a \in F \}$ and $x = c_1 x^0 + c_2 x^1 + \dots + c_n x^n$ for some scalars $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$ in $F$ and $x \in \text{span}(S)$.

Therefore, we also have $W \subseteq \text{span}(S)$.

Since $\text{span}(S) \subseteq W$ and $W \subseteq \text{span}(S)$, $W = \text{span}(S)$.